# Python 3 Import error AttributeError: '_ModuleLock_' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, import, attributeerror

I'm updating a package from python 2 to 3 and I cannot get imports to work. Even the easy ones like import math or import os. Everything checks out ok when I run it with idle.

If I try to run it through terminal I get a failed to load process message. In debugger it runs through a few file paths and always gives the same error.
I've read a lot of documentation on imports and I'm fairly certain the imports are correct.

```
import os
...
import logging
...
...
import argparse

log = logging.getLogger(__name__) 


ap = ArgumentParser()
```

I've found this documentation to confirm im doing these right.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Cant post last link to os

So everything seems right, but when I run my code I can tell I get no output from argparse, which prompted me to run debugger. 
The following is the error I got.

for os

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path_to/Apps/python/py-scripts/new/untitled.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 148, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 174, in _get_module_lock
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 59, in __init__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 59, in __init__
  File "C:\path_to\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\bdb.py", line 48, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "C:\path_to\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\bdb.py", line 66, in dispatch_line
self.user_line(frame)
  File "C:\path_to\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\idlelib\debugger.py", line 24, in user_line
    self.gui.interaction(message, frame)
AttributeError: '_ModuleLock' object has no attribute 'name'
```

for logging

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path_to/Apps/python/py-scripts/new/untitled.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 148, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 174, in _get_module_lock
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 59, in __init__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 59, in __init__
  File "C:\path_to\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\bdb.py", line 48, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "C:\path_to\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\bdb.py", line 66, in dispatch_line
    self.user_line(frame)
  File "C:\path_to\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36 \lib\idlelib\debugger.py", line 24, in user_line
    self.gui.interaction(message, frame)
AttributeError: '_ModuleLock' object has no attribute 'name'
```

In posting this I notice its calling libraries from AppData and not where I installed python. Is that normal as well?

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error message. The most likely issue is that something in your current path is clashing with a built-in module; the error message can help diagnose this.

Comment: Mr. Martijn Pieters, I have since updated the question to reflect a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, or so I think. Pls remove the hold so that one may be able to assist if possible.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this, and the traceback doesn't immediately tell me what is going on either, but I've reopened it anyway. Note that the paths may be those recorded in the `.pyc` files why whomever created the Python distribution you installed and not necessarily reflect your own filesystem.

Comment: Never mind, it's 3.6.3.

Comment: I think this is a bad interaction between the IDLE debugger and the bootstrap module locking code. An empty `_ModuleLock` instance is created and `__init__` is being called on that instance. But the `name` attribute is being set on line 61, so *before* that point anything that might trigger an attempt to look at that attribute *from a different thread* might end up with that exception. Why there is another thread trying to load the attribute `name` is not yet clear.

Comment: Is there a better way to track down this error? I've heard of other ide's that may be better at this than stock idle. I'm just not familiar with any. before this I used 2.7 and everything just worked. I'm trying to make the transition into 3.6.3. so far I've met a few headaches, but theres been plenty of documentation that's made it bearable. So far I haven't been able to get any of the programs I'm updating to work.

Comment: Maybe your right and there's a bad interaction between those two. Idle does not complain about imports. I only went the route of using debugger because I could not get it to work.. Maybe I'm just not familiar with how to set up my projects in 3.6. Should I post a new question and ask if my setup.py is correct? Again I did not use a virtual environment. I had not used one in the past.

Comment: Without knowing why this exception is happening it is impossible to say if this is a bug in IDLE or something in your IDLE setup that triggers the problem. I find it strange that the `self.gui.interaction()` line is the last, for example, because `self.gui` is another Python-defined class, I'd expect Python to have made it into that `interaction()` method too.

Comment: The only other info I could give is that there was a KeyError: 'logging' that happened here importlib. bootstrap. get module lock() line 166.  Other than that I am at a loss. I don't remember an error like this in 2.7 but I don't remember needing to run debugger on an import call either.

Comment: Would it be better for me to ask a new question, related to why I cannot get an output out of argparse in 3.6 and I can in 2.7? This is what led me down the path of running debugger in the first place. The only problem is I really would have trouble giving a minimal example of the code. Is it uncouth to post a link to a gitlab or dropbox?

Comment: I think your problem with importing modules is a symptom of the deeper problem. *Something is broken for your installation*. It is not the code you posted, not the specific modules you imported. We are unlikely able to reproduce the exact situation. I don't think a link to gitlab or dropbox would even help here, but yes, that is otherwise also frowned upon.

Comment: I'd try to find another machine with Python 3.6 and see if you can get your code working *there* to rule out a broken local installation.

Comment: So are you saying, that simple `import os` will fail when debugged in `idle`?

Comment: I don't see how this was a fresh install of windows 7 pro 64 bit and a fresh install of python 3.6.3. I had another issue and completely reinstalled everything. this was the same errors I was getting before... Albeit its still the same machine.

Comment: so far, in my instance that statement is true.

Comment: The issue with argparse has been halfway solved. Instead of ap = ArgumentParser(), It should be ap = argparse.ArgumentParser().

Comment: ok so I have duplicated the error on a second machine. windows 7 pro 64 bit, Fresh install of python 3.6.3. albeit this problem seems irrelevant to running programs, it seems it is a bug.

Comment: What else could I use to debug? pycharm?

Answer (score 2):

i had this issue when import caffe and had the same error. It turns out the python, when running, is not calling caffe library at the right location. So i manually has sys.path.append("right_path"), fill in there where your packages are installed. This solved my problem.