# Python 3 Import error AttributeError: '_ModuleLock_' object has no attribute 'name' when script invoked from c++

Tags: python, c++

I am having a problem with embedding python script in my c++ code. It's very similar to this one: [Python 3 Import error AttributeError: '_ModuleLock_' object has no attribute 'name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716027/python-3-import-error-attributeerror-modulelock-object-has-no-attribute-na) although there was no c++ code involved. Btw that issue was never resolved. Here is standar c++ code, nothing unusual there:

```
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"/home/me/my-project\")\n"
            "sys.path.append(\"/home/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages\")\n"
            "sys.path.append(\"/usr/local/lib/python3.7\")\n"
            "sys.path.append(\"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload\")\n"
            "sys.path.append(\"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages\")");

    PyObject* moduleName = PyUnicode_FromString("my_module");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(moduleName);
    Py_DECREF(moduleName);
```

my_module has a couple of import statement to other libraries which are I think irrelevant. What's important I think is that the same import statement sometimes succeeds and sometimes fails so it's not deterministic and the problem seems to be only related to the packages from virtual env and not the standard python packages. The code runs fine if invoked from python. The error is of course:

**File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 117, in **repr****

**AttributeError: '_ModuleLock' object has no attribute 'name'**

**Failed to load "/home/me/my-project/my_module.py**

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a few days I finally resolved the issue. It turned out to be similar to the issue with IDLE. In my case it was tracing function that tried to access arguments of each function call at print them, thus tried to use **repr** function before the object had been initialized.